# Mysql Incorrect date format while inserting

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When was trying to insert some data to a table, I encountered this error. `Incorrect datetime value: 'dweadwaed' for function str_to_date`.
I was using `INSERT INTO  .. SELECT` method to do it. The SELECT query works fine, but when I combined it with the insert query, the error happened.

```
SELECT id,'INVALID_DATE' FROM invoice WHERE STR_TO_DATE(paid_date, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL
```

This query returns the row 1,3.
And these 3 rows should have been inserted into the `validation` table using the below query. But it is showing error.

```
INSERT INTO validation(invoice_id,validation_message)
SELECT id,'INVALID_DATE' FROM invoice WHERE STR_TO_DATE(paid_date, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL
```

Basically the select query is same, and I am not trying to insert any date field to the DB too.

Can anyone explain the reason for this behaviour of Mysql.

I have added a [SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mV64UHTP3Cc63oQvfZTZ4A/0) for the 2 tables

*We are trying to migrate data from an external application. So we cannot change the existing DB structure. Instead we are trying to identify and correct their invalid dates.*

Comment: This looks like a (rather arcane) MySQL bug.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you don't store dates as `VARCHAR`. Use the proper `DATE` data type to get rid of all these issues.

Comment: @TheImpaler We are trying to migrate data from an external application. We cannot  change the existing DB structure. Instead we are trying to identify and correct their invalid data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is there any workaround for this. Or any other method that we can Identify if the string is a valid date.

Comment: Since date will always be in the format YYYY-MM-DD, I was thinking of using REGEX for identifying the incorrect data. But still need to idenfity wrong dates like 0001-12-12

Comment: @NandakumarV . . . That is a correct date.  If you have a range in mind, you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

1. paid_date is Varchar(50)
2. you have inserted dweadwaed' for paid_date

Select list contains this value for paid_date  so the error

Comment: . . If you look at the Fiddle, you will see that the columns in question are both strings.  The date conversion is happening "in-between" and your answer is simply not relevant to this question.